# SlideDown multiple elements at once

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div for a form

```
<div class="form" style="display:none">
```

inside this div, I have several divs

**Example**

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'comment'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'comment',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>140)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'comment'); ?>
</div>
```

I'd like to slidedown all the div **smoothly**.

I simply tried

```
$(".form").slideDown(2000);
```

it slidedown div by div which give a very ugly effect.  How to slidedown as it was a single div ?

**the complete form is the following**

```
<p>
    <div class="form" style="">
        <form id="comment-form" method="post" action="/post/index.php/comment/create>
            <p class="note">
            Fields with
                <span class="required">*</span>
                are required.
            </p>
            <div id="comment-form_es_" class="errorSummary" style="display:none">
                <p>Please fix the following input errors:</p>
                <ul>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <label class="required" for="comment_comment">
                Comment
                <span class="required">*</span>
                </label>
                <input id="comment_comment" type="text" name="comment[comment]" maxlength="140" size="60">
                <div id="comment_comment_em_" class="errorMessage" style="display:none"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <label class="required" for="comment_type_id">
                    Type
                    <span class="required">*</span>
                </label>
                <input id="comment_type_id" type="text" name="comment[type_id]">
                <div id="comment_type_id_em_" class="errorMessage" style="display:none"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row buttons">
                <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" name="yt0">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</p>
</div>
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Can you post a fiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net ) ?

Comment: Can you do $(".row").slideDown(2000);?

Comment: @Mathias it's likely that "row" will be used in other places. I suggest using a unique ID or class name.

Comment: Check this simple example http://jsfiddle.net/BluAngel/VKTyq/ it works fine if it is not work in your code then give unique ID or Class to main div (try other than form)

Comment: @BluAngel  your example works even when I add display:none to start without showing the wrapper div. Thank you for your help. I'll try now to apply in my code and I keep you informed

Comment: It works better now. Thank you @BluAngel

Comment: Glad to know it helps you @sanfisa

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the code which you are showing. Please take a look at this **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tssj5/)**

Answer (score 3):

Wrap them all with a single DIV, then slide that parent DIV down.

If you are already doing that, then it is likely that there are other divs with class="form" on them - probably being generated by the  tags. Change the parent div to a unique class name or ID and slideDown that instead.

Comment: it is what I did @Joshua and it slides down div by divs and it jerky

Comment: Can we see the output of the PHP function? It is likely that there are other divs with class="form" on them. Change the parent div to a unique class name or ID and slideDown that instead.

Comment: I updated my post with the code of the form. I use Yii framework @Joshua

Comment: @sanfisa Please update your code with the HTML output as rendered by the web browser. The PHP code is not useful for your issue.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus  I replace the php code with HTML output